# Having troubles configuring protobuf in my Gradle Kotlin project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. I followed many guides and always am stuck with the resolution of the `protoc` plugin call of `protobuf` plugin in my gradle kotlin `build.gradle.kts` file.

Here is my whole file:

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.14")
    }
}

plugins {
    id("com.google.protobuf") version "0.8.14"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.10.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.4.21"
}

group = "com.myapp"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_15

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")

    // gRPC
    implementation( "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:3.14.0")

    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.grpc:grpc-testing")
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        proto {
        }
    }
    test {
        proto {
        }
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact("com.google.protobuf:protoc:0.8.14")
    }
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "15"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Whatever I try

```kotlin
protobuf {
    protoc { // <<<
        artifact("com.google.protobuf:protoc:0.8.14") // <<<
    }
}
```

this part can not be resolved and causes the following error:

```
> Configure project :
Could not resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.4.21
e: /home/xetra11/Development/projects/user-service/build.gradle.kts:52:5: Unresolved reference: protoc
e: /home/xetra11/Development/projects/user-service/build.gradle.kts:53:9: Unresolved reference: artifact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this on [Github](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/issues/460).

You need import `com.google.protobuf.gradle.protoc` for protoc.

`artifact` is a property (instead of a function) for the protoc locator, so it should be `artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:0.8.14"`.